Power Query output not as a table or allow spill function in table
I am trying to create a dynamic data compiler for a number of sharepoint spreadsheets. This is for a monthly report, so the sheets I'm pulling from are in a different folder each month (Oct_Data_2024, Nov_Data_2024, Dec_Data_2024 eg).
I have tried using power query to pull this data directly, but it has been inconsistent at the best of times due to security and admin access blocks.
I have a relatively painless way of getting all of the addresses of my folders, sub-folders and the sheets held therein, leaving me with:
'https://umaritime.sharepoint.com/-more address stuff-/Oct_Data_2024/Inputs/Misc/[Misc_Data.xlsx]Sheet1'!
'https://umaritime.sharepoint.com/-more address stuff-/Oct_Data_2024/Inputs/Sales/[Sales_Data.xlsx]Sheet1'!
'https://umaritime.sharepoint.com/-more address stuff-/Oct_Data_2024/Inputs/Invent/[Inv_Data.xlsx]Sheet1'!
'https://umaritime.sharepoint.com/-more address stuff-/Oct_Data_2024/Inputs/Ovr-hd/[OH_Data.xlsx]Sheet1'!
'https://umaritime.sharepoint.com/-more address stuff-/Oct_Data_2024/Inputs/Purchasing/[Purch_Data.xlsx]Sheet1'!

There are close to 50 sheets, above is just and example.
Since all of this is input by different departments, and people being people, refuse to standardize, I WANT to use a Filter() function to scoop a large, blanket array (A1:Z99999) and filter out the blank rows. From there, I can Power Query the data into a useable format.
I created a spill formula that generates a number of FILTER() functions:
=Filter('https://umaritime.sharepoint.com/-more address stuff-/Oct_Data_2024/Inputs/Misc/[Misc_Data.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A1:Z99999,'https://umaritime.sharepoint.com/-more address stuff-/Oct_Data_2024/Inputs/Misc/[Misc_Data.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A1:A99999<>"","")

In the formula bar, however, they're:
="=FILTER("& INDEX/MATCH TO FIND THE RIGHT PATH &"$A1:Z99999,"& INDEX/MATCH TO FIND THE RIGHT PATH &"$A1:A99999<>"&CHAR(39)&CHAR(39)&","&CHAR(39)&CHAR(39)&")"

ETC
And I tried to use Power Query to convert those resulting formulas into text, and use find/replace the '=' sign to simultaneously activate the now complete formulas. But because Power Query outputs as a table, and FILTER() is a spill formula, they just give me a spill error.
Is there a way to have Power Query output as an unformatted range of data? If not, is there a way to allow spills in a table?
Otherwise, is there a better way to pull this data in dynamically?
Thank you for your time.
I tried to use a combination of FILTER() and Power Query to pull in data from various sheets who's address change monthly.

Is there a way to have Power Query output as an unformatted range of data? If not, is there a way to allow spills in a table?
No and now. You can only output as a table but you could convert table to range using VBA.

As @Michal wrote, the answer to both your questions is No. I would suggest first trying to figure out why you can't just download the files directly into PQ, and then reformat them. If you can't do that, and you have another method of obtaining those files, pull them using that method, then have PQ access those pulled files.
